# org.hibernate.cache.CacheException: Unsupported access type [read-write]

Tags: hibernate, caching, jboss, ehcache

I am trying to enable second level caching using EhCache but facing problem in my server startup. When I specify @Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE) for my DTO class, I am getting below errors:

> 16:20:42,882 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation]
>   (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014612: Operation ("deploy") failed -
>   address: ([("deploy ment" => "PORTAL.ear")]) - failure description:
>   {"JBAS014671: Failed services" =>
>   {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"PORTAL.ear#AppPU\"" => "org.jb
>   oss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.persistenceunit.\"PORTAL.ear#AppPU\":
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit:  AppPU]
>   Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
>       Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: AppPU] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
>       Caused by: org.hibernate.cache.CacheException: Unsupported access type [read-write]"}}

If I use CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY, I am not facing any startup issues.

**Below is my persistence.xml:**

```
<persistence-unit name="AppPU" transaction-type="JTA">
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
<jta-data-source>java:jboss/myDS</jta-data-source>
      <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
      <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
      <properties>
          <!-- Auto-detect entity classes -->
          <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm"/>

          <!-- Print sql executed - useful for debugging -->
          <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
          <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false"/>

         <!-- Properties for Hibernate -->
         <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup"/>
          <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
          <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="net.sf.Ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhcacheProvider"/>
         <!--  <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory"/> -->
        <property name="net.sf.Ehcache.configurationResourceName" value="/ehcache.xml"/>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true"/>
       </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
```

I want to use READ_WRITE to enable second level caching.

Can someone please help me on this issue? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To configure ehcache, you need to do two steps**:

configure Hibernate for second level caching
specify the second level cache provider

**Hibernate 4.x and above**

```
<property key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</property>
```

**Hibernate 3.3 and above**

```
<property key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory</property>
```

**Hibernate 3.2 and below**

```
<property key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.provider_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider</property>
```

***[reference](http://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/hibernate-ehcache-configuration-tutorial/)***

Comment: Hi, @nilesh thanks for you inputs. I tried with the solution you provided but now getting a different error below:

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation in interface itable initialization: when resolving method "org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.Eh
CacheMessageLogger_$logger.log(Lorg/jboss/logging/Logger$Level;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V" the class loader (instance of org/jboss/module
s/ModuleClassLoader) of the current class, org/hibernate/cache/ehcache/EhCacheMessageLogger_$logger, and the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules
/ModuleClassLoader) for interface org/jboss/logging/BasicLogger have different Class objects for the type org/jboss/logging/Logger$Level

Comment: when I am seeing the EhCacheRegionFactory class it is present in ehcache-core-2.611.jar, ehcache-2.7.8.jar and hibernate-ehcache-4.3.10.Final.jar. Is the error because of multiple jars having the same class name.

Comment: can you please go with only one appropriate jar ? and then do clean from project menu and still issue exist then once restart your eclipse.